# $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] with #hash too?

Tags: php, ajax, hash, request

If i request `site/page.php#hash` the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is only `/page.php`.

Is there a way to know in php (without later ajax) that the user requested the page with `#hash`?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The hash isn't passed to the server, it exists only on the client-side. This is by design. If the solution to your problem involves needing to know the hash server-side, you've chosen the wrong way to go about it.

Comment: you could however query the server using ajax on the clientside to get the hash to the server

Comment: @Alex The question specifically stipulates **without later ajax**.

Comment: ah I see, didn't pay full attention sorry. Had the same problem a while ago and I solved it that way

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use php's `$_GET` method (instead of using hash(#))?

```
if(isset($_GET['hash'])){/*do something*/}
```

The # is only on the client side and php cannot access it.

Comment: no problem, I guess it seems abit like it since the down voter didn't provide a comment :)

Comment: lol. yes. just a lil bit. now noone will even consider my answer bc of the `-1` hehe